# object has no attribute 'get' in django views

Tags: python-3.x, django, docker, django-rest-framework, rest

I am using the django version   3.0.11.
I am going to make rest api using rest_framework.
I think there is no problem url router and other parts.

```
class DemoAPI(
    mixins.ListModelMixin, 
    mixins.CreateModelMixin, 
    mixins.UpdateModelMixin, 
    mixins.DestroyModelMixin
    
):
    model = Demo
    serializer_class = DemoSerializer

    def __init__(self, obj, **kwargs):
        obj = super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.bUseDefaultGetParam = False
        return obj

    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset = self.get_queryset()
        if self.request is dict:
            query = self.request.GET.get('q', None)
            if query:
                condition = Q(demo_name__icontains=query) | Q(api_number__icontains=query)
                queryset = self.model.objects.filter(condition)
            else:
                queryset = self.model.objects.all()

        serializer = DemoSerializer(queryset, many=True)

        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        null_api = "0000000000"
        null_apis = Demo.objects.filter(api_number=null_api)
        demos = Demo.objects.exclude(api_number=null_api)
        context["null_apis"] = null_apis
        context["mapbox_access_token"] = os.getenv('MAPBOX_ACCESS_TOKEN')
        context["well_markers"] = []
        for demo in demos:
            if not demo.surface_hole_longitude or not demo.surface_hole_latitude:
                continue
            context["well_markers"].append(
                {
                    'name': demo.demo_name,
                    'location': [
                        float(demo.surface_hole_longitude),
                        float(demo.surface_hole_latitude),
                    ]
                }
            )
        
        context['data'] = serializer.data

        print("demos: ", serializer.data)
        return Response(context)
```

When I tried  to call this api, an error is occured.

```
AttributeError at /api/demos/
'DemoAPI' object has no attribute 'get'
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/api/demos/
Django Version: 3.0.11
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:    
'DemoAPI' object has no attribute 'get'
Exception Location: /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/livereload/middleware.py in process_response, line 22
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python3
Python Version: 3.7.3
Python Path:    
['/app',
'/usr/lib/python37.zip',
'/usr/lib/python3.7',
'/usr/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload',
'/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages',
'/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages']
Server time:    Sun, 14 Mar 2021 17:43:21 +0000
```

My project is running on docker container.

I don't really know why it happends. Could you help me please to solve this problem?

Comment: Why do you return something in the `__init__` method? `__init__` is not supposed to return anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A get request is being made to an API object that does not have a get method. Usually for a list API, a get method calls a list method such as the one provided.